# Android Edittext in a Adapter not receiving focus

Tags: android, android-edittext, focus, cart

I have a edittext with other view inside a LinearLayout. I am using this layout as listview item. I have but instead of listview I am using a vertical LinearLayout to add these items because listview is not able to handle focus properly. So now wheni click on one of the edittext and then click on other it receives focus but cursor disappears. I am trying to implement CART sort of thing.

Answer (score 2):

add follwing line to listview

```
android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
```

and add following line to activty manifest

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

Comment: try adding android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" this to your manifest inside activity

Comment: android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants" add this line to your listview xml

Comment: android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"  this is working fine just tried dont need to do anything else

Comment: actually what i did now in my adapter i commented out the setOnFocusChangeListener() and now its working fine.

Comment: i guess i need to restrict that value of that edittext can be change when clicking done button of the keyboard what i was doing was changing it when edittext looses focus

Comment: but now the problem is focus always goes to 1st edittext of the list. the cursor is always showing.

Comment: actually parent layout for my list item is a linear layout so i have set a OnTouchListener on that and in that i am removing keyboard and focus of that views edit text

Comment: list.setItemsCanFocus(true); before setting adaper and android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" to activity should solve your problem check

Comment: android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants" keep this line in listview also and above together will work

Comment: actually i am not using a listview to display these items i am using a vertical linearlayout because it avoids focus problems